# Is Perl cpan's 2.4 Spreadsheet::WriteExcel entirely compatible running code written for its preceding 2.2 version?

Tags: perl, cpan

There is in-use application running the 2.2 version that cannot risk interruption of the users. Features in the 2.4 version would be very helpful in our future developments. Is there someone in this community that knows the extent of this libraries particular update to reveal to me that the older code base won't be rendered defunct by the desired update.

Comment: According to the [`Changelog`](https://metacpan.org/source/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/Changes) the 2.4 release was in 2013, and the 2.2 release was from 2007, and there was a lot of intermediate releases betweeen. So it seems likely that they are not completely compatible

Comment: It's version 2.40, not 2.4. And the module is now in maintenance mode. You should consider using [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) instead.

Comment: @DaveCross I have always disagreed with that presentation, even though it's one the author has pushed. They create incompatible file formats. Your choice is not whether to use a more modern module, but whether to use a different file format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to know for sure if a new release of something will break existing functionality is to have a very good 100% coverage unit test suite against the existing code.

Set up a development/staging environment, install the new version, and ensure the existing test suite passes.

I say "very good 100% coverage", because a test suite can have 100% coverage, but if as many edge cases as possible aren't tested, the suite isn't good.